# How many times has Superman caught the falling Daily Planet statue?

Tags: dc, superman, trope

When and how many times has the Daily Planet's statue (of the eponymous Daily Planet) at the top building fallen and been caught by Superman?

Comment: The answer is dozens. It happens at least once a season in every Superman medium which makes this a "list" question;  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-V4N13Hej8 +  http://www.supermanhomepage.com/images/superman-returns3/sup-flying-globe-tb.html + http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_2_209 +  http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Wkk5csNhIM8/0.jpg + http://cdn.anthonyscomicbookart.com/Images/Category_2/subcat_1419/bullock_globe.jpg

Comment: This is a limited-list question, and per our current policies is technically on topic. We have many examples of such questions. It's not an infinite list or an open-ended, opinion-based list. I nominate this for re-opening.